# Date and time batch or delim

Tags: datetime, batch-file

What I'm looking for is a batch file or delim that discovers the current date and time and puts it in different lines in a text file, eg:

output of text file:

```
[date]                  (does not change)
2011/02/01              (new line)
13:34:00                (new line)
```

Can find loads of `%date%` and `%time%` in batch files but it gives the answer in one line. Help.

Answer (score 1):

You can just echo two lines separately (in batch):

```
rem This will append the date and time on separate lines
echo The date: %date% >> output.txt
echo The time: %time% >> output.txt
```